# is it possible via {$define xx} to define an constant value (like CompilerVersion)

Tags: delphi

is it possible via {$define xx} to define an constant value (like CompilerVersion). For example I would like to do something like

```
{$define FrogCount=25}
```

but seam to not work :(

I need to do this inside a myincfile.inc file because I need to do stuff like

```
interface

   {$I myincfile.inc}

uses
  {$IF FrogCount = 25}
  toto;
  {$else}
  lala;
  {$endif}
```

and you understand that here I can't do stuff like

```
const FrogCount = 25;
```

inside myincfile.inc else I have a compiler error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Delphi, you *cannot* define a constant value in a `{$DEFINE ident}` statement, you can define only the `ident` name by itself, which is then usable only with `{$IF(N)DEF ident}` and `{$IF (NOT) DEFINED(ident)}` statements.

In FreePascal, you *can* define a constant value in a `{$DEFINE ident:=expr}` statement, but only when `{$MACRO ON}` is enabled. See [Macros](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progse5.html) in FreePascal's documentation.